# python remove variable substring patterns from a long string in a python dataframe column

Tags: python, string, dataframe, replace

I have a column in my dataframe, containing very large strings.
here is a short sample of the string

> FixedChar{3bf3423 Data to keep}, FixedChar{5e0d20 Data to keep}, FixedChar{6cb86d9 Data to keep}, ...

I need to remove the recurring static "FixedChar{" and the variable substring after it that has static length of 6 and also "}"
and just keep the "Data to keep" strings that have variable lengths.
what is the best way to remove this recurring variable pattern?

Answer (score 0):

It was easier than I thought.
At first I started to use `re.sub()` from `re` library.
regex `\w*` removes all the word characters (letters and numbers) after the "FixedChar" and the argument `flags = re.I` makes it case insensitive.

```
import re
re.sub(r"FixedChar{\w*","",dataFrame.Column[row],flags = re.I)
```

but I found str.replace() more useful and replaced the values in my dataFrame using loc, as I needed to filter my dataframe cause this pattern shows up only in specific rows.

```
dataFrame.loc['Column'] = dataFrame.Column.str.replace("FixedChar{\w* ",'',regex=True)
dataFrame.loc['Column'] = dataFrame.Column.str.replace("}",'',regex=True)
```